# Using Valgrind to Debug Use After Free

Tags: c++, debugging, valgrind

I am trying to debug a use after free error in my code using Valgrind.

My code is crashing when it tries to access an object that was previously deleted. Is there some way to see who deleted the object in this case using Valgrind?

I ran Valgrind using the following option, but it only catches the crash, and shows where it occurred. I'm hoping to get details on where the object was deallocated:

> valgrind --tool=memcheck

Comment: `cout << ptr << '\n';` before every `free(ptr);` Analyse the output. It's called debugging. Why are you using `free` in C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's irrelevant. Just address of pointer you are about to free wont help you. Invalid `free()` is undefined behavior, you cannot rely that it'll be always crash.

Comment: If he writes pointer values and `__LINE__` and some other context in the proper places, it is not "irrelevant" at all; it is rudimentary debugging and has been for many decades.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I'm using the delete command. I just said use after free because that is the term I've seen before. I guess it would technically be use after delete in my case.

Comment: I've started trying to go through and add print statements before each delete statements, but it is a rather large codebase that I am working on, and it will require considerable work to do (I have already started trying to do this). I was hoping Valgrind would be able to help me.

Comment: @xur17: Okie doke sounds good so far. You are on the right track =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I use in these cases:

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes
```

In case of a use-after-free, it will show you the stacktrace of the function that free'd the memory/deleted the object.

Please read the manpage of Valgrind for the caveats, specifically the ones about performance. If your issue is a concurrency problem, a slower Valgrind might change the timing properties of your program and possibly change (either reduce or increase) the probability to hit the bug.

```
--track-origins=<yes|no> [default: no]
    Controls whether Memcheck tracks the origin of uninitialised
    values. By default, it does not, which means that although it can
    tell you that an uninitialised value is being used in a dangerous
    way, it cannot tell you where the uninitialised value came from.
    This often makes it difficult to track down the root problem.

    When set to yes, Memcheck keeps track of the origins of all
    uninitialised values. Then, when an uninitialised value error is
    reported, Memcheck will try to show the origin of the value. An
    origin can be one of the following four places: a heap block, a
    stack allocation, a client request, or miscellaneous other sources
    (eg, a call to brk).

    For uninitialised values originating from a heap block, Memcheck
    shows where the block was allocated. For uninitialised values
    originating from a stack allocation, Memcheck can tell you which
    function allocated the value, but no more than that -- typically it
    shows you the source location of the opening brace of the function.
    So you should carefully check that all of the function's local
    variables are initialised properly.

    Performance overhead: origin tracking is expensive. It halves
    Memcheck's speed and increases memory use by a minimum of 100MB,
    and possibly more. Nevertheless it can drastically reduce the
    effort required to identify the root cause of uninitialised value
    errors, and so is often a programmer productivity win, despite
    running more slowly.

    Accuracy: Memcheck tracks origins quite accurately. To avoid very
    large space and time overheads, some approximations are made. It is
    possible, although unlikely, that Memcheck will report an incorrect
    origin, or not be able to identify any origin.

    Note that the combination --track-origins=yes and
    --undef-value-errors=no is nonsensical. Memcheck checks for and
    rejects this combination at startup.
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it is exactly what I am looking for! It's crashing now, and Valgrind is catching it, but I am having some issues (I'll explain in the next comment). I did have some issues with Valgrind not crashing due to it running slower / being multithreaded, but I fixed this by removing a lot of the statements printed during execution.

Comment: It's now crashing with the message: `Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Access not within mapped region at address 0x0` I'm unsure what exactly this means though.

Comment: @xur17 That means that Valgrind caught a NULL pointer dereference (`Access not within mapped region at address 0x0`), and forwarded it to the process using its default action, that is it terminated the program.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind has shown you maximum it could. You need to compile your code with more debug information - then valgrind will be able to show you more information such as file, function and line.

Compile your code with `-g` option and rerun with valgrind. On some compilers there is also -gN where `N` is level of debug. But in most cases, `-g` is sufficient.

Comment: I'm getting the backtrace for where it crashed, and the exact line number that it crashed on, but nothing about where the object was previously deleted. I do have the -g option enabled right now.

Comment: @xur17 I'm sure valgrind does it. Read all reports from valgrind. When you work with invalid memory its memory error and it doesnt mean there is necessary crash. Look for invalid read/write.

Comment: @xur17 Or... when you know where the problem is, try to analyze how it was made and i think you'll get it.

Comment: It crashes with a segfault. The problem is that the error only occurs some of the time, it's a multithreaded program, and I am still becoming familiar with the code base. I've spent quite a few weeks trying to debug this, and I am pulling my hairs out trying to figure it out.

Comment: I've been looking through the Valgrind documentation, but I haven't found anything about debugging this yet.

Comment: @xur17 You can try to put segfault i.e. ((char*)0)=0; to the destructor of object you want. Valgrind will tell you where it was deleted. Also, if you havent so, take a look at ReferenceCounting.